# For loop through a segment of an array

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script

I need to loop through an array using the `for` clause, but starting at some specific index and just to a maximum of iterations.

The code below does the task, but it looks awful to me: it's there a better way?

```
  var offset = 10, max = 5;
  for (var i = 0; (i + offset) < data.length && i < max; i++) {
    doSomething(data[i + offset]);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly you would just need to initialize i to the offset.

```
var offset = 10, max = 5 + offset;
for (var i = offset; i < data.length && i < max; i++) {
    doSomething(data[i]);
}
```

edit: didn't understand the max at first.